# Css style is not applied in Firefox

Tags: html, css

This is very dumb question. But I do not know how to solve the issue.
I have the following html/css code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Selectors and Grouping</title>
  <style type=”text/css”>
    p {
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 14pt;
    }
    
    h1 {
      color: black;
      border: 5px solid black;
    }
    
    h2 {
      color: orange;
      border: 4px solid orange;
    }
    
    h3 {
      color: blue;
      border: 3px solid blue;
    }
    
    h1,
    h2,
    h3 {
      letter-spacing: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    Heading 1
  </h1>
  <h2>
    Heading 2
  </h2>
  <h3>
    Heading 3
  </h3>
  <p> Selectors choose the element to apply formatting to. grouped together.
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

html headings must be enclosed in boxes and have different colours. However, when I open the document in Firefox browser it displays the page without any style applied. Online validators point to no error. So the issue must be related to firefox. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to close the html `</html>`

Comment: Replace `type=”text/css”` by `type="text/css"` and disable smart quotes in your editor.

Comment: @athimohan your edit (if approved) removes the actual error

Answer (score 1):

You have following errors :

1) There were incorrect quotes in `<style type=”text/css”>`. Change it to proper double quote:

```
<style type="text/css">
```

2) You are missing one < in doctype declaration as per above code you have mentioned in question.

3) You haven't closed the `<html>` tag

Comment: Man, thank you very much. It's all about quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from this part :

```
<style type=”text/css”>
```

Your quotes are not the good ones. Use :

```
<style type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 0):

look at your style tag :

```
<style type=”text/css”>
```

change to normal double quote

```
<style type="text/css">
```

and close you html tag at the end